# Non-Latin input in emacsclient

Tags: macos, emacs, unicode, emacsclient

When run in foreground mode, Emacs inserts non-Latin input correctly.

It's when I run it as `emacs --damon` + `emacsclient`, begins the madness. Each keystroke, which should insert a character, results in an action, like selecting words, jumping around expressions, selecting functions and so on. Almost like (a horrifying thought) Vim!

Is there a configuration option I am missing?

**Update:**

Actually solved it: <kbd>M-x</kbd> `set-locale-environment` <kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>.

It's still not clear why it doesn't use the system-wide locale settings (UTF-8).

**Update 2:**

Yay, fixed in trunk! Thanks to the one who did it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your emacsclient sessions are running in a tty and that for some reason Emacs thinks you're running in an ASCII-only terminal where the 8th bit of bytes marks the use of the Meta key.  What does `locale` return when you run it inside your tty?

Comment: Stefan, it returns `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: @katspaugh: Try it via `M-x report-emacs-bug RET`; I find stackoverflow unusable for debugging that requires back-and-forth discussion.

Comment: @katspaugh: by the way, please try with an empty `~/.emacs` first.

Comment: Stefan, I've sent the bug report. Thanks!

Comment: Do you perhaps have a link to the bug report? I still seem to be experiencing this bug, or at least a similar one.

Comment: Looks like it's https://debbugs.gnu.org/11926 and apparently we dropped the ball on this one, since noone even replied to it.